# How to resolve data mismatch when querying relational database at different time intervals

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table in postgres that has columns `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` with both timestamps being in `UTC`. Whenever a new record is inserted `created_at` and `updated_at` will be equal but whenever a user alters a record, the `updated_at` changes to the time of update.

My issue is when I run

**SQL**
`select count (id) from table1;`
Immediately (time *x*) and the rerun again after *x+20 min*, the difference between both records is **446**
but the I run
`select count(id) from table1 where updated_at >= x-3hrs and updated_at <= (x+20min)-3hrs;` I get **33** records

What I'm I missing? I expect the records to match i.e 446

**NB** I'm using dveaver for querying the db on my machine with timezone `UTC+3`, wheareas the db is running on a remote server with timezone `UTC`

Comment: can you provide the details , table structure, data sample, and output of both queries

Comment: Your first query doesn't have a limit of 3 hours, for one thing.